# Jquery ui ranges

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

My jquery-ui range slider behaves illogically. Can anyone explain why only one of the sliders here work? Note that on the actual page there are more than 2 sliders.

http://jsfiddle.net/uVeUD/

The point of this code is to change all my sliders at once using variables in the code. However, as you can see in the fiddle, if it does not have the same value as min, it will not work. What is the reason for that?

```
$( "div.slider-div" ).each(function(){
    obj = $("input", $(this).parent());
    $(this).slider({
       range: "min",
       value: obj.val(),
       min: obj.attr("min"),
       max: obj.attr("max"),
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $("input", $(this).parent()).val( ui.value );
           $("input", $(this).parent()).change();
       }
    });   

    obj.val( $(this).slider("value") ); 
});
```

I need things that work so I am open to alternative suggestions for sliders if no one can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is global, and you're passing strings and not integers to the options of the slider :

```
$(".slider-div").each(function () {
    var obj = $(this).siblings('input');
    $(this).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: parseInt(obj.val(),10),
        min  : parseInt(obj.attr("min"),10),
        max  : parseInt(obj.attr("max"),10),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $(event.target).siblings('input').val(ui.value).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVeUD/2/)

You could also set the options for the slider with data attributes.

Comment: @WooCaSh - your answer works just fine, but it works because the slider will get the options from the data attributes, the issue is really passing strings to options that expect integers.

Comment: That why I love SO. Even if I'm wrong I can learn something from others.

Comment: It's the base, as in decimal, otherwise you'd risk get octals instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change attr to `data-val` instead of `val`. Look here:

```
<input type="range" style="border:0px;margin-left:10px;" value="40" data-min="8" data-max="72" id="shadow-size-2">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVeUD/1/

Is it what you want?